# Getting the default nav menu of grails 3.1.2 to span to all classes

Tags: jquery, html, grails, nav, gsp

[The Nav Bar of Grails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9aSI.png)

to stay put where it is, however when you move to a different page, like localhost/user, it disappears, it only shows up in grails home index. any idea how I can get it to stay put?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Inventory System</title>

    <asset:link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <content tag="nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Users <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><g:link class="user" controller="user" action="create">Create</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="user" controller="user" action="index">Users List</g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Expenses <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><g:link class="expenses" controller="expenses" action="create">Create Expenses</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="expenses" controller="expenses" action="index">Expenses List</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="type" controller="type" action="create">Create Types</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="type" controller="type" action="index">Types List</g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clients <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><g:link class="client" controller="client" action="create">Create</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="client" controller="client" action="index">Clients List</g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Assets <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><g:link class="supply" controller="supply" action="create">Create Supplies</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="supply" controller="supply" action="index">Supplies List</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="supply" controller="supply" action="create">Create Item</g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="supply" controller="supply" action="create">Asset Item List</g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </content>

    <div class="svg" role="presentation">
        <div class="grails-logo-container">
            <asset:image src="grails-cupsonly-logo-white.svg" class="grails-logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content" role="main">
        <section class="row colset-2-its">
            <h1>Inventory System</h1>

            <ul>
                Welcome to the Inventory System created for the final requirement of ITWB303 Advanced Web Programming class.
                Presented to Engineer Jomin Yu, the professor of the class.
            </ul>
            <ul>
                Created by the group of Krizia Genica Simon and Harold Jesse Co.
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move div (in this case whole `<content tag="nav">`) with menu to separated template and include this template in layout.

Than you can set specified layout in views where you want this menu.

Comment: You sir, are very much correct. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes. Didn't think of that :) again thank you